# Finding XML data and Converting it into CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv

JUst need some quick help. Let say i have the following xml formatted like so:

```
<Solution version="1.0">
   <DrillHoles total_holes="238">
     <description>
       <hole hole_id="1">
         <hole collar="5720.44, 3070.94, 2642.19" />
         <hole toe="5797.82, 3061.01, 2576.29" />
         <hole cost="102.12" />
       </hole>
    ........
```

EDIT: Here is the code i used to create the hole collar..etc.

```
for row in reader:
    if i > 0:
        x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2,cost = row
        if current_group is None or i != current_group.text:
            current_group = SubElement(description, 'hole',{'hole_id':"%s"%i})

            collar = SubElement (current_group, 'hole',{'collar':', '.join((x1,y1,z1))}),
            toe = SubElement (current_group, 'hole',{'toe':', '.join((x2,y2,z2))})
            cost = SubElement(current_group, 'hole',{'cost':cost})
    i+=1
```

and so on, how do i obtain the hole collar, hole toe, and hole cost data. Here is my piece of code so far, i think i am really close.

```
with open(outfile, 'w') as file_:

     writer = csv.writer(file_, delimiter="\t")
     for a in zip(root.findall("drillholes/hole/hole collar"),
             root.findall("drillholes/hole/hole toe"),
             root.findall("drillholes/hole/hole cost")):
        writer.writerow([x.text for x in a])
```

Although my program generates an csv file, the csv file is empty which is why i think this piece of code was unable to obtain the data due to some search and find errors. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't specify, but I assume you're using xml.etree.ElementTree. There are a few issues here:

1) XML is case-sensitive. "drillholes" is not the same thing as "DrillHoles".

2) Your path is missing the "description" element found in your XML.

3) To refer to attributes, you don't use a space, but another path element prefixed with an "@", as in "hole/@collar".

Taking those into consideration, the answer should just be this:

```
 for a in zip(root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/hole/@collar"),
              root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/hole/@toe"),
              root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/hole/@cost")):
   writer.writerow([x.text for x in a])
```

But it's not. Testing this, it seems findall really doesn't like returning attribute nodes, probably because they don't exist as such in etree's API. So you could do this:

```
 for a in zip(root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/hole[@collar]"),
              root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/hole[@toe]"),
              root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/hole[@cost]")):
   writer.writerow([x[0].get('collar'), x[1].get('toe'), x[2].get('cost')])
```

But if you have to list out the attributes in the statements in the for loop anyway, personally I'd just do away with the zip and do this:

```
for a in root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole"):
  writer.writerow([a.find("hole[@"+attr+"]").get(attr) for attr in ("collar", "toe", "cost")])
```

Comment: So lets say if i didn't have "hole" infront of collar,toe,cost, it would just be                                                       for a in zip(root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/collar"),
                 root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/toe"),
                 root.findall("DrillHoles/description/hole/cost")):
            writer.writerow([x.text for x in a])